# I want to change order of billing address on checkout page in magento 2

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, billing-address

[image: please check it and replay back thanks]

please help me to solve this, It's very urgent

Comment: how do you want it to be ordered? what have you tried?

Comment: Currently It's show as in ascending order but i want to it's descending order